# Is there a way to create bookmark in view mode in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, bookmarks

A new bookmark can be added when we try to edit a report in Power BI. Is there a way we can add and update/delete it when user opens the report in view mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible for someone without editing permissions to create new bookmarks.

However, [personalized bookmarks](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31788253-personalized-bookmarks) are a popular idea that Microsoft has stated they've started working on (5/21/2018), so I'd expect it to be released in one of the upcoming monthly updates.